# Codeigniter: Extending CI_Exceptions not working in 2.2.1

Tags: codeigniter

I have an issue with my custom 404 page in codeigniter. The below code works fine in 2.2.0 but having upgraded to 2.2.1 i'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object in /application/core/MY_Exceptions.php on line 14
```

MY_Exceptions.php    (/library/core/MY_Exceptions.php)

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
}

public function show_404() {

$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('form');
$CI->load->helper('text');
$CI->load->model('Pages_model');

$data['nav'] = $CI->Pages_model->getPages();


$CI->output->set_status_header('404');
$CI->load->view('header', $data);
$CI->load->view('error404', $data);
$CI->load->view('footer', $data);
echo $CI->output->get_output();
exit;
}
}
```

I thought maybe it should now be located in /application/libraries but when placed in here I just get the standard codeigintor 404 error page?

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no need for create instance in this folder  /application/core/
 $CI =& get_instance(); 
you can access helper function by
$this->load->helper('form');

Comment: I tried removing '$CI =& get_instance();'   and replacing '$CI ->' with '$this->' but I get the following error:  Message: Undefined property: MY_Exceptions::$load   - I thought you needed $CI =& get_instance(); to reference the super object?

Comment: It seems to be working again now? I'm thinking maybe the page/browser hadn't fully loaded? A bit werid?....

Comment: try to change function name  show_404  to other